# What is the name of the language used to define the following syntax?

Tags: syntax

```
[ FROM {<table_source>} [,...n] ]

<join_type> ::=
[ INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } ]
[ <join_hint> ]
JOIN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) or the [extended version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)?

Answer (score 2):

It's called Backus-Naur form, although this looks like some non-standard variant. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form